# Inequality involving square root of $x$

Tags: inequality

I am reading an article in which they state the following fact:

If $a,b,x>0$, then $x\leq a\sqrt{x}+b$ implies that $x\leq a^2+b$.

I think the proof of this should be pretty trivial, but I cannot figure it out. I have tried squaring both sides of the first inequality and then using the quadratic formula, but it does not turn out as the second inequality. Could someone please help?

EDIT: As people have pointed out in the comments, this statement is not true. What I think is true (could someone confirm?) is that for $a,b,x>0$, $x\leq a\sqrt{x}+b$ implies $x\leq 2a^2+2b$. This is seen by noting that

\begin{align*}
x&\leq \frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}+b\\
&\leq \frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a\sqrt{(a+2\sqrt{b})^2}}{2}+b\\
&= a^2+a\sqrt{b}+b\\
&\leq 2a^2+2b
\end{align*}

In the article I read, the inequality is used with an unfixed constant before $a$ and $b$, so I think the result they obtain by using the inequality is true, even though the statement itself is not.

Comment: $x=1,$ $a=b=1/2.$ Then $a^2+b=3/4.$

Comment: Don’t believe everything you read.

Comment: The only difference in the inequalities is $a\sqrt x$ is replaced with $a^2$ which seems to imply that $a$ is somehow bigger than $\sqrt x$.   As no relation or restrictions are made this seems arbitrary and not guaranteed.  I'd try to find an example where $a^2 + b < x \le a\sqrt x + b$ or $a^2 < x-b \le a \sqrt x$.  Lest so $a=1$ and we want $\sqrt x > a$ so say $x = 4$ and we have $a^2=1< x-b=4-b \le a\sqrt x = 2$.  Okay. $b$ can be anything that makes that true $1 < 4-b \le 2$ so say $b= 2.5$.  ... We have a counter example.

Comment: Hmm, what they might mean is if $x\le a\sqrt x + b$ for *ALL* $b> 0$ then $a\le a^2 + b$.  See $x -b \le a\sqrt x$ for *all* $b>0$ actually would imply $x\le a\sqrt x$ (do you see why?) and so $a\ge \sqrt x$ and so $x \le a^2 < a^2 + b$.  But this is only if it is true for *every* possible $b$, not just one $b$.  Was this an article about real analysis and least upper bounds?... Actually, the more I think about it the article was probably just out and out wrong.... It happens.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x = a \sqrt{x} + b$ when $t = \sqrt{x}$ satisfies the quadratic
$t^2 = a t + b$, so $t = (a \pm \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b})/2$, but since $b > 0$,
$a -  \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b} < 0$ so only $t = \sqrt{x} = (a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b})/2$ works,
and then $$ x = \frac{\left(a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b}\right)^2}{4} = \frac{a^2 + a \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b}}{2} + b $$
Since $b > 0$, this is greater than $a^2 + b$.  We conclude that there are **no** $a, b > 0$ for which $0 < x \le a \sqrt{x} + b$ implies $x \le a^2 + b$.

Comment: there are no $a, b, x > 0$ for which $x = a \sqrt{x} + b$ implies $x \le a^2 + b$. isn't more accurate?

Comment: I guess I should have included $x > 0$ for clarity.  Of course if $x < 0$, $x \le a \sqrt{x} + b$ makes no sense because $a \sqrt{x} + b$ is not real.

Comment: I mean you only analyzed the equality case

Comment: @Redshoes If for a given $a$ and $b$ it was true for $0 < x \le a \sqrt{x}+b$, then it would be true in particular when $x = a \sqrt{x}+b$.

Comment: My comment was certainly minor. I did not see any mistake in your argument.  I thought you were making a stronger argument (there are *no*...) compared to a toy counter-example. Otherwise, simplifications like $a =\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ or many other things reveal countless counter-examples.